# resize iframe after inner form submit

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with a form inside an iFrame.  the form is rather long so the iframe is long.  After the form is submitted the form goes away and a message comes up at the top of the inner page.  However because the initial iframe is so long when the user submits the see a nearly white page unless they scroll up to the top.

On submit of the form (in the iframe) I need to be able to go to the top of the iframe. On successful submit I tried this (writing jQuery via PHP) in the success code:

```
echo ("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n");
echo ("$(document).ready(function() {\r\n");
echo ("$(\"html, body\").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, \"slow\");\r\n");
echo ("});\r\n");
echo ("</script>\r\n");
```

But this didn't work (didn't do anything, and Firebug showed now JS error)

Also tried to pot a span like this at the top of the iframe page:
    
and in the form use #top as my action but it didn't work either.

Any thoughts on either going to the top of the iframe after submit or to "shrink" the size of the iframe based on its contents?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can only animate css properties, and scrollTop is not one of those. I would do it like this:

```
$(document).scrollTop(0);
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to animate the scrolling, I've never run into that before.

**edit**: the easiest way to achieve an animated scroll effect here would probably be to animate the height of the element that causes your iframe to be so long. Something like this:

```
$('#CONTAINING_EL_ID').animate({height: 20}, 'slow');
```

It will have a similar effect of seeming to scroll up (though really the content is just getting shorter), until it all fits in the view.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  If it can do the smooth scroll up that is good but it is more important that I get to the top of the page, even if its without the scroll.  Will try this on Monday.

Comment: Monday?? What you got a 9-5? Programmers never sleep!

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  Should this be in the iframed page or the parent?

Comment: Also noticed I got this: Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
Line 16

Comment: You can't access properties of elements outside of an iframe from within an iframe; it's a security issue. This includes properties of the iframe itself, though not its children. So to manipulate elements outside an iframe, you should have the code within an iframe. To manipulate the iframe or elements of the parent page, the code must be in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a load callback on the iframe itself from the parent page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myIframe").load(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);

        iframe.animate(
            {height: iframe.contents().find("body").outerHeight(true)},
            "slow",
            "swing"
        );
    });
});
```

This will change the size, based on the height of the `<body>` in the iframe, each time the iframe finishes loading its contents.  Note that this should be placed in a docReady in the parent page.

Comment: Will give this a try on Monday.

Comment: Added this to the parent page, no luck:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#merchantprofiles").load(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);

        iframe.animate(
            {height: iframe.contents().find("body").outerHeight(true)},
            "slow",
            "swing"
        );
    });
});
</script>
             
<iframe src="http://www.<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/iframe_pages/advertise.php" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" id="merchantprofiles"></iframe>